# Getting errors (already defined variable in if statement)

Tags: javascript, error-handling

I am getting errors in JSlint and JSFiddle, however the scripts works perfectly.

I want to fix the errors, but I don't really know what to do.

The error I am getting is: **'allmonth is already defined'**

**The javascript (it's just a part of a full script, but here's the part with the errors)**

```
$.each(data.product.variants, function (index, variant) {
     var oldvartitle2 = variant.title,
         oldvartitle = oldvartitle2.substring(oldvartitle2.indexOf(":") + 1),
         newvartitle = oldvartitle.substr(3),
         splitted = newvartitle.split(' '),
         month2 = splitted[1];
     if (month2 === 'januari') {
         var allmonth = '01';

     }
     if (month2 === 'februari') {
         var allmonth = '02';

     }
     if (month2 === 'maart') {
         var allmonth = '03';

     }
     if (month2 === 'april') {
         var allmonth = '04';

     }
     if (month2 === 'mei') {
         var allmonth = '05';

     }
     if (month2 === 'juni') {
         var allmonth = '06';

     }
     if (month2 === 'juli') {
         var allmonth = '07';

     }
     if (month2 === 'augustus') {
         var allmonth = '08';

     }
     if (month2 === 'september') {
         var allmonth = '09';

     }
     if (month2 === 'oktober') {
         var allmonth = '10';

     }
     if (month2 === 'november') {
         var allmonth = '11';

     }
     if (month2 === 'december') {
         var allmonth = '12';

     }
     var allmonths = splitted[0] + '/' + allmonth + '/' + splitted[2];
     $('.multiple_' + index2 + '_variants .datacursusul_' + index2 + '_ul').append('<li class="' + allmonths + '">' + oldvartitle + '</li>');
 });
```

I want to change the 'allmonth' variable to a number depending on what the month2 variable contains.

Thanks!

Comment: Declare `var allmonth;` at the top of the scope, and then just use `allmonth = '01'` &tc for all the assignments.

Comment: use a switch statement or an object

Comment: was just about to suggest that as well. You should really consider using a switch statement here along with declaring allmonth at the top of the scope.

Comment: Or a data dictionary/object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must declare all memory at the beginning of your code blocks to be jslint compliant. So `var allmonth;` should be part of the var at the very beginning. Like so

```
 var oldvartitle2 = variant.title,
     oldvartitle = oldvartitle2.substring(oldvartitle2.indexOf(":") + 1),
     newvartitle = oldvartitle.substr(3),
     splitted = newvartitle.split(' '),
     month2 = splitted[1],
     allmonth;
```

You must also remove the var from the other `allmonth` variables.

Similarly with `allmonths`.

Answer (score 1):

```
 var allmonth = '';
 if (month2 === 'januari') {
          allmonth = '01';

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are much more concise ways to do something like that.  One is to replace that series of "if" statements with a "switch" statement.  But the way I would do it is like so:

```
var month_names = ['januari', 'februari', 'maart', 'april', 'mei', 'juni', 'juli', 'augustus', 'september', 'oktober', 'november', 'december'];
var month_index = month_names.indexOf(month2) + 1;
var allmonth = ("0" + month_index).substr(-2);
```

Note that if no match is found, allmonth will be "00".

(Edited to return a two-digit string with zero padding.)

Answer (score 1):

As stated above it's probably undeclared allmonth. You could however sligthly refactor your code:

```
var data = {
    product: {
        variants: ['maart']
    }
}

$.each(data.product.variants, function (index, variant) {
    function pad(number) {
        return number < 10 ? '0' + number : number;
    } 
    var month2 = variant,
    months_order = ['januari', 'februari', 'maart', 'etc'],
    allmonth = pad(months_order.indexOf(month2) + 1);
    console.log(allmonth); // 03

});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xZN8P/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array to store the month names and then just use `indexOf` to get the index and pad it out with a zero where applicable.

```
var monthList = ['januari', 'februari', 'maart', 'april', 'mei', 'juni', 'juli', 'augustus', 'september', 'oktober', 'november', 'december'];

var month2 = 'maart';

function getMonth(month) {
  var num = monthList.indexOf(month) + 1;
  if (num === 0) return null;
  return num.toString().length === 1 ? '0' + num : num;
}

console.log(getMonth(month2)); // 03
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/qJun4/)